# How transpose a table in SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, query-performance

I have this table in Teradata, with this query:

```
select column1, column2,column3 from squema.table;

column1 column2 column3 count
ab1      ab2    tip1    123
ab1      ab2    tip2    23
ab1      ab2    tip3    5
```

I was trying a tranpose,but I didn't find a good sample to obtain this table in Teradata:

```
column1 column2  tip1  tip2 tip3 
ab1      ab2      123    23   5
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `column3` doesn't make sense in the result set.

Comment: Yes, I going to modify that. Thanks.

Comment: What's your Teradata release?

Comment: Teradata 16 supports [pivot](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/GnnbigJTnAWrDfLbecAN7Q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use case when

```
   select column1, column2,max(case when column3='tip1' then count end) as tip1  
    ,
    max(case when column3='tip1' then count end) as tip2,
    max(case when column3='tip1' then count end) as tip3
     from squema.table group by column1, column2
```